# How to use multiple double-dash(--) in one command line

Tags: bash

for example

```
ssh root@me -- cat /etc/hostname -- cat /etc/hostname
```

I expect it output:

```
me
me
```

but it output

```
me
me
cat: cat: No such file or directory
```

I know the double-dash means ending parsing option, why it raise `cat: cat: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`--` signals the end of option parsing. Nothing after `--` will be treated as an option, even if it begins with a dash. As an example, `ls -l` will print a file listing in long format while `ls -- -l` looks for a file named `-l`.

```
ssh root@me -- cat /etc/hostname -- cat /etc/hostname
```

This sshes to a remote server and runs the command:

```
cat /etc/hostname -- cat /etc/hostname
```

That is a single cat command. Skipping over the `--`, it's equivalent to writing:

```
cat /etc/hostname cat /etc/hostname
```

It prints `/etc/hostname`, which is `me`. It then tries to print the file `cat`, which doesn't exist, giving the error `cat: cat: No such file or directory`. The program cat is complaining that the file `cat` doesn't exist. Then it prints `/etc/hostname` again.

---

If you want to execute multiple commands with ssh, do this:

```
ssh root@me 'cat /etc/hostname; cat /etc/hostname'
```

or this:

```
ssh root@me <<CMDS
cat /etc/hostname
cat /etc/hostname
CMDS
```

Comment: If `--` is the end of option parsing, what does `grep -- -v /tmp/try` mean?, what is the binary for `-v /tmp/try`

Comment: `--` means end of option parsing. So any arguments even if they begin with `-`, will be interpreted literally. e.g. `rm -rf dir` will recursively remove `dir`. `rm -- -rf filename` will remove 2 files `-rf` & `filename`

Comment: `grep -- -v /tmp/try` would try to match the regular expression `-v` in `/tmp/try`.

Comment: [Bash doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) (Shell Builtin Commands)